# MySQL-8.0.11 "...LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED" does not works with multiple sorts?

Tags: mysql, multithreading

I have a table with a task queue.
Each task can have a status of "new" or "ready."

I use several threads, each of which should take one "new" task and after some time update it to the "finished" one.
Each thread uses this request:

```
....WHERE `status` = 'new' ORDER BY `service` LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
```

And it works.
But if I add 1 more sorting criteria, the query from the first thread returns one record, as expected, But the other threads get an empty result.
It looks like the second sorting criteria locks all the records in the table.
How to get around this?
thank

steps to reproduce:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`service` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`status` enum('new','done') NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `service`, `adders`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'service_1', 'adders_1', 'new'),
(2, 'service_2', 'adders_2', 'new');
```

Request for each thread:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `status` = 'new' 
ORDER BY  `service`, `address` LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
```

Then pause like sleep(). 
Then

```
UPDATE `test`  SET.....
```

then

```
COMMIT;
```

Comment: what is the additional column you try to sort by, is it locked does it have any other criteria or conditions set on it?

Comment: added more info

Comment: Are you certain that your table is accurate and you didn't forget to mention an index (on `service`)?